# Unit testing dynamically-rendered elements in Polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, chai, wct

#### Overview

DOM elements that are dynamically-rendered within `dom-if`, `dom-repeat` `<templates>` seem to be rendered asynchronously thus making unit-testing a bit of a pain.

---

#### The Polymer Component

```
template(is='dom-if', if='{{!defaultPrintAll}}')
  template(is='dom-repeat', items='{{_pageBucketItems}}')
    button(type='button', class$='{{_computeDefaultClass(item)}}', on-tap='_togglePageClick') {{item}}
```

#### The Test

```
  test("Clicking 'Export All' to off, reveals board-selection tiles", function() {
    $("#export-pdf-checkbox-all").siblings(".checkbox").trigger("click");
    Polymer.dom.flush()
    expect($(".board-range__button")).to.be.visible;
  });
```

---

#### Why it seems to fail:

When clicking a button which triggers the `dom-if`/`dom-repeat` the elements don't render in a synchronous order.

- The `dom-if` and it's subsequent/nested `dom-repeat` render asynchronously.
- To make matters worse, the `button` itself get's it's class in a computed/binded manner (mind the `class$=` on the `button`).

So the question boils down to this:

Is it possible to *force render* the `dom-if`, `dom-repeat`, and the computed-binding of the class in a *synchronous* order after I simulate the click to the button which activates all 3 of those conditions?

---

**Notes:**

- I'm using Polymer's official WCT as the test harness.
- I'm also using chai-jquery.
- I've also used `Polymer.dom.flush()` but it still doesn't, ahem.. flush.
- I'm aware that I can use `chai-as-promised.js` instead but it adds unnecessary complexity to my tests for a trivial matter such as this, so I'd like to avoid it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than using `Polymer.dom.flush()`, try using the `flush` function that WCT puts on the window. This will enqueue a callback function to be executed, in theory, after the template has rendered.

```
test("Clicking 'Export All' to off, reveals board-selection tiles", function(done) {
    $("#export-pdf-checkbox-all").siblings(".checkbox").trigger("click");
    flush(function () {
        expect($(".board-range__button")).to.be.visible;
        done();
    }
});
```

Important to notice: Asynchronous tests require the done function to be passed into the test callback, and require done to be called after your conditions have been evaluated.

Comment: bingo - thanks, but how is this much different than using `setTimeout()` in the tests? How would I be able to continue the next tests which depend on this?

Comment: See for yourself: https://github.com/Polymer/web-component-tester/blob/b5c2774aa050975b9414eba1ffe6c71cc97fa0fb/browser/environment/helpers.js#L97 In most cases, there's no real difference compared to just using setTimeout with an arg of 0. The reason you would want to use window.flush instead of setTimeout, however, is that in future versions of web-component-tester, flush's implementation may change to be smarter and/or more useful.

Comment: And as far as the next tests go, those tests won't be executed until the previous test either calls it's done function, fails by assert, or fails by timing out.